# Android studio , variable inheritance from a class inserted in a class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a login screen in Android Studio and i want to use the email taken from a database , use it to login , and then show it into another activty where you can see your profile. The problem is that i can't use the "email" variable value into another class because it's nested into a class inside of a class.If i try to declare it static it says "Inner classes cannot have static declarations.

This is the code:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity 
{

....

private  class Send extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
     {

   String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
........

     }

}
```

Is there any way that i can return the email value so that it can be used in another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to pass data between activities. The first and foremost way is to using `Intent`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("name", "value");
```

And in your `NewActivity`, access the value using:

```
String extra = i.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: It works flawlessly, thank you very much, i tried so many things, thank you!

Comment: Cheers! I'm glad to know it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Since it you want it after logging in then you can save it in preference, in this method it can be available throughout your application context.

```
public SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
settings.edit().putString("EMAIL", theemail).apply();
```

then you can get it anywhere in you application by using :

```
settings.getString("EMAIL", "");
```

Another advantage of this method is that if the database profile information can be updated or changed in your app then all you need is change the value of the **EMAIL** preference using :

```
settings.edit().putString("EMAIL", newemail).apply();
```

**NOTE :** You might need to have a base activity to make this very effective.